# How to authorize a public client

Tags: authentication, oauth, api

I've created an application that is exposed via a web service and an Android client that communicates with that web service. Is there a way to have the client authenticate with the web service so that the web service knows it's communicating with the Android app I wrote and not an application masquerading as my Android app?

Comment: You can't effectively prevent someone from imitating the app. Even if you establish some sort of "secret app token" and encrypt the communication, it will be possible to reverse-engineer that and mock the app behavior.

Comment: Right. Hence why public clients are not to be issued client secrets in OAuth 2. So the remedies for impersonating an Application would have to be legal rather than technical?

Comment: @redwoolf the solution could be practical - don't give any reasons for someone to impersonate your app. If it's good there will be no point for someone else to imitate it, and if they do then implement whatever features the copycat apps have so that users no longer have reasons to use those.

Comment: @redwoolf Yes, in my opinion looking for a sound technical countermeasure is a waste of time. You'd just get into the usual battle of "weird obfuscation vs. patient reverse-engineering".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't effectively prevent someone from imitating the app. Even if
 you establish some sort of "secret app token" that only the app uses and encrypt the
 communication, it will still be possible to reverse-engineer these measures with manageable effort and mock
 the app behaviour.

Comment: @arminius - Your comment is so good it deserves to be an answer. I have made this a community wiki please feel free to edit or delete this answer

Answer (score 0):

You might add a client side certificate to the TLS (https) communication. Upon first usage your app retrieves a certificate from the server. For subsequent requests the app has to present its certificate in the TLS handshake.

You need to make sure though, that only valid users get a client certificate (i.e. one time password via SMS/text). And you need to store the certificate in secure way.